# Why my dojox.grid.DataGrid doesn't display the loadingMessage?

Tags: datagrid, dojo

My datagrid doesn't display the loading message like"loading..."
Does anyone know how to confirm it?

---

my datagrid's code as below.
I have set the loadingMessage as "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
but it doesn't display when the page loaded.

```
<div>
    <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"  query="{sort_value:'*'}" loadingMessage="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" id="myDataGrid" structure="myDataGridStructure" style="width:100%; height:450px;" noDataMessage="No agent information. Please create.">
          <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="sort_value">Agent ID</th>
                    <th field="value" class="hidden">Agent ID</th>
                    <th field="name">Agent Name</th>
                    <th field="descr">Description</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

---

I set the store with a method as below.
I used the setStore method to give the data to the grid.

```
function loadGrid(){
selectItmeMsg = "";
dojo.byId("agentFilter_selected").value="";
var xhrArgs = {

        url: "agents.json",
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data){
            if(data.error_message == null){
                var bStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(
                        {clearOnClose:true, 
                         data: {items: data.agents}}
                        );
                agentStore_selected = bStore;
                var x = dijit.byId("myDataGrid");
                bStore.fetch( {
                    query :{},
                    onComplete : function(items, request){
                        if (x.selection != null){
                            x.selection.clear();
                        }
                        x.setStore(bStore);

                        if(items.length == 0){
                            dijit.byId("editBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                            dijit.byId("delBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                            dijit.byId("agentFilter_selected").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                        }else{
                            dijit.byId("editBtn").setAttribute('disabled', false); 
                            dijit.byId("delBtn").setAttribute('disabled', false); 
                            dijit.byId("agentFilter_selected").setAttribute('disabled', false); 
                        }
                    }
                })
                dojo.byId("errorDis").innerHTML = "";
                dojo.byId("agentFilter_selected").value = "";
            }else{
                dojo.byId("errorDis").innerHTML = data.error_message;
                dijit.byId("editBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                dijit.byId("delBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                dijit.byId("newBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                dijit.byId("agentFilter_selected").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
            }

            if(data.jdbcTemplateNull!=null){
                dojo.byId("errorDis").innerHTML = "Primary CMS is down.";
                dijit.byId("editBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                dijit.byId("delBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
                dijit.byId("newBtn").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
            }
        }
}
dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

}

---

Comment: How long does it take your data to load ? Maybie it's loading too quickly for the message to be displayed ? Try to put a setTimeout in your load function to make it last longer if that is the case... just for testing of course...

Comment: What is it displaying instead?  I understand that the loading message and error message are i18n-enabled, so they may not be a simple property override.

Comment: I have thounds data for display,so I think there is enough time to show the loading message.